# Sorting raw data workbook vba

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to sort an entire raw data workbook based on smallest to largest in column C. This ensures that, in this case, the pole #'s are sorted in order on the output excel file. I am using VBA for this and cannot seem to figure it out. Below is my existing code.

```
Sub ECOECCSV()
Dim desPathName As Variant
desPathName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *.csv*", Title:="Please select a file")
If desPathName = False Then
    MsgBox "Stopping because you did not select a file. Reselect a destination file through the menu"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=desPathName
    Set des = Workbooks.Open(desPathName, True, False)
End If
ActiveSheet.Name = "RawData"
Set RDBook = Worksheets("RawData").Parent

Workbooks.Add
If Worksheets.Count > 2 Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' prevent are you sure message while deleting
Sheets("Sheet3").Delete
Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
lastcolumn = 1
Do While HomeSheet.Cells(1, lastcolumn) <> ""
lastcolumn = lastcolumn + 1
Loop

lastrow = 2
Do While HomeSheet.Cells(lastrow, 1).Value <> ""
HomeSheet.Cells(lastrow, PoleNum) = CDbl(HomeSheet.Cells(lastrow, PoleNum))
lastrow = lastrow + 1
Loop
sortColumn = Cells(1, PoleNum).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, 
ColumnAbsolute:=False)
sortEnd = Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, 
ColumnAbsolute:=False)

HomeSheet.Range("A1:" & sortEnd).Sort key1:=HomeSheet.Range(sortColumn), 
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Sheets(1).Name = "Make-Ready"
Set MRBook = Worksheets("Make-Ready").Parent
```

"Raw Data" Worksheets is the input file that will be used in the macro, that is the document I want the pole #'s sorted. "Make Ready" is the document that will be output. from lastcolumn = 1 to Header:=xlYes is my code that is not working.

Reminder: my goal is to sort the entire sheet based off that one column.

Comment: ```PoleNum``` is never assigned a value, that might be causing some issues.

Comment: I think it is having an issue with the line Do While RDBook.Cells(1, lastcolumn).Value <> ""

Comment: Thats what the debugger says! @warcupine

Comment: Recommend you put `Option Explicit` above your sub.  This will ensure you have declared your variables.  Also a good idea to indent your code so that it is easier to read.

Comment: Also to help clean up your code, you can find the last row and last column this way: 

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'change second number to column in question
    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'change first number to row in question